# Converting VB project to C# project how to convert "My Project" Folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am attempting to convert a VB project into a C# project by hand.  There is a ton to do, and as you might imagine, it is not all intuitive.  My old VB project had a My Project folder.  In visual studio 2012 it is represented by a wrench in the solution explorer.  In it there is a resoruces.Designer.cs file, Resources.resx, Settings.Designer.cs, Settings.settings file, etc.  I am assuming most of these are native to VB apps.

I am thinking of just excluding the thing all together and adding pieces back in one by one.  I am thinking that the settings file will be needed.

In a couple of places I have a reference to My.Settings and was trying to figure out how to convert that into an app.config file, or another kind of file.

Any advice?

Comment: None of those files are vb-specific. You'll need them in your new C# project as well.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you take a look at Instant C# (http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com). They do a great job of converting entire VB projects to C# (we've used their app on numerous large projects).

Comment: I know there are solutions out there to convert entire projects, but they are not an option right now,  I just want to convert the My.Settings file in my VB project into a Properties.Resources file or maybe an app.conf file (with app settings and such) I can then replace all the references to the My.Settings file with references to an App.config.ConfigSection call or similar.  I don't want to have to rewrite the entire My.Settings file... Maybe I will have to...